# Why I can't see my App rendering in the browser(Marionette.js tutorial)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new in Marionette.js and I've been following the tutorial that is in the web page of marionette which is based in the 2.4 version and somethings are changed since this version. The current version is 3 (the one I need to learn), so I've followed the todo tutorial and while doing it I tried to check out the documentation of the version 3 and changed some things to make the tutorial work for the new version.

**The Problem:**

I cant see my app in the browser and also I get no console errors, I may not understand everything in the version 3 documentation because I am not to experienced but I need to learn this for my new job. I hope someone can give me an advice of how to solve this problem.

Here is the code:

**driver.js**

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
var TodoView = require('./views/layout');
var ToDoModel = require('./models/todo');

var initialData = [
      { assignee: 'Scott', text: 'Write something'} ,
      { assignee: 'Andrew', text: 'do more' }
];

var App = new Mn.Application({
   onStart: function(options) {
     var todo = new TodoView({
          collection: new Backbone.Collection(options.initialData),
          model: new ToDoModel()
     });
     todo.render();
     todo.triggerMethod('show');
   }
});

App.start({ initialData: initialData });
```

**views/layout.js**

```
var Bb = require('backbone');
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
var ToDoModel = require('../models/todo');

var FormView = require('./form');
var ListView = require('./list');

var Layout = Mn.View.extend({
  el: '#app-hook',
  template: require('../templates/layout.html'),

  regions: {
     form: '.form',
     list: '.list'
  },

  collectionEvents: {
     add: 'itemAdded'
  },

  onShow: function() {
     var formView = new FormView({ model: this.model });
     var lisView = new ListView({ collection: this.collection });

     this.showChildView('form', formView);
     this.showChildView('líst', listView);
  },

  onChildviewAddTodoItem: function(child) {
     this.model.set({
         assignee: child.ui.assignee.val(),
         text: child.ui.text.val()
     }, { validate: true });

     var items = this.model.pick('assignee', 'text');
     this.collection.add(items);
  },

  itemAdded: function() {
     this.model.set({
         assignee: '',
         text: ''
     });
  }
});

module.exports = Layout;
```

**views/form.js**

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');

var FormView = Mn.View.extend({
   tagName: 'form',
   template: require('../templates/form.html'),

   triggers: {
   submit: 'add:todo:item'
   },

   modelEvents: {
      change: 'render'
   },

   ui: {
     assignee: '#id_assignee',
     text: '#id_text'
   }
});
module.exports = FormView;
```

**views/list.js**

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette')

var ToDo = Mn.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: require('../templates/todoitem.html')
});

var TodoList = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    childView: ToDo,
});

module.exports = TodoList;
```

**models/todo.js**

```
var Bb = require('backbone');

var ToDo = Bb.Model.extend({
  dafaults: {
    assignee: '',
    text: ''
  },

  validate: function(attrs) {
    var errors = {};
    var hasError = false;
    if (!attrs.assignee) {
        errors.assignee = 'assignee must be set';
        hasError = true;
    }
    if (!attrs.text) {
        errors.text = 'text must be set';
        hasError = true;
    }

    if (hasError) {
        return errors;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = ToDo;
```

Comment: Put some `console.log` or use breakpoints in the Dev Tools to see what is called and what is not called. This will narrow the problem to a certain section. This is the basics to debug any application in any language.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to try to create a [mcve]. Remove all the noise from the project and start with the bare minimum for the app to run or to reproduce the problem. Then, instead of _"dumping"_ the whole project in the question, only show the relevant parts, which ideally should only be a few lines.

Comment: This way, the question has more chance to be answered as it takes a lot less time to test and see the problem. In addition to this, the question could be more useful to others then it is right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mn v3 does not have an `onShow` for views.. while it is being triggered here I would recommend you avoid it: https://github.com/marionettejs/guides/issues/43

But you also need to make sure the DOM has a `$('#app-hook')` when the app is run.